# Ajax call to Asp.net WebApi not works

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I making the simplest ajax call to the WebApi Asp.Net, but does not working problem is unknown

I tried all solutions on StackOverFlow and other forums, I even found similar peoples that had similar questions but there is no answer.

```
<form id="form2">
<div>
    <label for="status">Status</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="status1" type="text" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
<span id="displayText"></span>
```

html file

```
$('#form2').submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/values/",
        method: "get",
    }).done(function (data) {
        $("#displayText").text(data);
    });
});
```

ajax call

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{

    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

my controller

Do I need to install something on my damn PC to make ajax working?

Comment: What do you mean by Not working? Are you getting any error? Add error handler function in Ajax call. Debug the web API code

Comment: Have you looked in the dev tools of the browser to see if you get any error messages?

Comment: Chetan Ranpariya, thanks for your advice I didn,t thought about it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because

> [Deprecated] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of 
>           its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

I changed async method

```
async: true
```

in ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/values/5",
    method: "get",
    error: function (request, status, error) {
       console.log(alert(request.responseText));
     },
    async: true
});
```